# Actualizacion de campo en DB con PDO

Tags: php, base-de-datos, pdo, update

Estoy pasándome a PDO recientemente y estoy tratando de hacer un Update pero siempre me retorna false, el código es:

```
$sql = "UPDATE pedido_pagos SET operacion, referencia, status VALUES (:operacion, :referencia, :status) WHERE idOpen = (:idOp)";
            $updateInfo = $connect->prepare($sql);
            
            $status = $updateInfo->execute(array(
                ':operacion'=>$operacion,
                ':referencia'=>$referencia,
                ':status'=>$estadoPay,
                ':idOp'=>$identificador
            ));
```

La conexión la hago en un archivo aparte, lo incluyo y genero el objeto connect, de hecho si hago Var dump del mismo me retorna los valores de configuración de la DB así que descarto una conexión fallida. Sabrán en que estoy fallando?

Comment: Saludos. Se que hay diversos Manejadores de Base de Datos que permiten ciertas sintaxis avanzadas y/o diferente de los normales; ¿seguro que la BD que usas permite esa sintaxis para el  `UPDATE`? ¿Cual es por cierto?

Comment: `UPDATE nombre_de_tabla SET campo1 = 'valor1', campoX = 'valorX' WHERE id = identificador`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código se ve claramente que estás usando consultas preparadas con PDO y marcadores de `:nombre`.

Tendrías que escribir la sentencia así exactamente:

```
$sql="UPDATE pedido_pagos SET operacion=:operacion, referencia=:referencia, status=:status WHERE idOpen =:idOp";
```

Todo lo demás está bien, los datos son pasados en el `execute` usando el marcador respectivo para cada uno. Salvo otro problema adicional, la consulta debería funcionar así sin problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, efectivamente el error se encontraba en como estaba estructurada la sentencia.